# Collecting birth dates in an Interactive Email Form Block

Tags: marketing-cloud, form, email-studio, date-picker, interactive-email

I'm really excited about the possibility to let subscribers submit data directly in a mail.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_create_create_an_interactive_email_form.htm&type=5

I've tested the setup and have successfully had subscribers without a first name submit this, stored the data in a data extension and built a journey in Journey Builder using that data extension adding that missing info on the account for that subscriber in Sales Cloud. Awesome.

But at the moment the real value for me would be to collect the birth date of my subscribers. Sadly date/time pickers are not available in Email form, only these data types are:

- Text
- Email
- Number
- Telephone
- URL

So, I'd find it extremely valuable to find a workaround for somehow capturing the birth date of the subscriber in the email form and map that info to a date field in the data extension.

**Anyone with an idea on how to accomplish this?**

Comment: as long as am aware, date format is not yet supported in interactive email content. Hopefully it will get added in upcoming releases. You can make a Text field and add a place holder (dd/mm/yyyy) so that customer can enter into those formats as a workaround.

Comment: Yeah your only option is to have it be a text value. What I would do then is to have an automation with a script activity 'validate' it at scheduled intervals and then have it push the valid dates into a DE that is used to start the journey to update. This is far from an optimal solution, but should give you enough of an interim solution without too much duct tape and bubblegum.

Comment: @Gortonington, Thank you, let me get this right :) so, data in my text-date form data extension would be processed and pushed into a true-date data extension in a Sales Cloud date format by a script activity. The script activity would also empty the entries in the text-date data extension to not revalidate and process those values again. The true-date data extension would be used as the entry source of a Journey, that would update the birthdate in Sales Cloud. Did I get everything right? Thank you

Comment: @FelixSanchez - That sounds about 100% on what I was saying.

Answer (score 4):

You can break the date down into multiple fields which would allow you a bit more control over the format.  For example, you could use a select input for the month and day and then have use a text input for the year.  The layout of those fields would be stacked, but you would have more control over the data captured.

[image: Stacked date field layout]